# Draggable Chrome Extension using iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, draggable, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am making a chrome extension that is currently using a default popup window that is not draggable. How can I change the code so that a draggable window contains an iframe of the program that is draggable in the window.

**This is my manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "draggable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Draggable",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "scripting", "webRequest"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "./frontend/modal/modal.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "./frontend/images/icon.png",
      "48": "./frontend/images/icon.png",
      "128": "./frontend/images/icon.png"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "type": "module"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "resources": ["**/*", "*"],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**And this is modal.html (the file i want to contain an iframe of the program):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
  <title>Draggable</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <iframe src="../../index.html" id="notesIframe" frameborder="0" title="Draggable"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```